# Difference between accessing class data members using self and not using it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, properties

if i have an outlet variable which i've declared as a property

```
@interface MyClass:UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

is there a difference between doing this

```
[label release];
```

and this

```
[self.label release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, when you're using a property, you're implicitly using an accessors, that is to say :

```
- (UILabel*)label;
```

So some additional behavior could be implemented in the getter, such as sanity check and so on.

Here you declared your property as retain :

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

So the setter will automatically retain the value to set, and release the old one.

Using :

```
[self.label release];
```

You are doing something hazardous, as you release the object which is retained by the accessors. So when you do something like :

```
self.label = nil;
```

It calls the method `- (void) setLabel:(UILabel*)label` which will release the actual object! So the object will be released twice, leading to freed object access!

If you declare a property, try to only use your member through this property !

You can also use some implicit member declaration, such as :

```
@interface MyClass

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* label;

@end

@synthesize label = _label;
```

A member `UILabel* _label` will be implicitly declared :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. in the second case you're using accessory methods. You should use either the first or `self.label = nil;` **not** `[self.label release];`

Why do you want to release an interface element?

Comment: Not only does `self.label = nil;` release `label`, but it also sets the variable to nil. This can prevent errors with objects still pointing to the released object. By using accessory methods, you also automatically update the Cocoa Bindings. Releasing it without setter would make it still the same for Cocoa Bindings but gone outside that. Releasing it via the getter is just waiting for crashes to come. You should NOT do it.